# How to set local database for google safe browsing update API (v4)?

Tags: google-api, documentation, local-database, safe-browsing

I am building a service for checking for phishing or malware URLs for one of my applications. This service will be running on google app engine. Now, I want to use google safe browsing's Update API (v4) to have local database of URL hashes. But I am having hard time to understand the setup process of the local database they have mentioned.

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/local-databases

They do provide a Go source code to do something of this sort but its not descriptive enough to have my own implementation.
I want to setup the db on google cloud itself. Can anyone point me to any good documentation or some ways to do the same if you have tried this before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
`"https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatListUpdates:fetch?key=" + apiKey;`
to download hash version database.

you may need send a post request to get the database according to `https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/reference/rest/v4/threatListUpdates/fetch`

Comment: Yes, I know how to download these hash version databases but I wanted to know how to store them or an example of how the table/database structure would/should look like. How or where to store them on google cloud like datastore or mysql or bucket.

Comment: @crucifix94 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-safe-browsing-api/rawhashes%7Csort:date/google-safe-browsing-api/xDd3FJYKKOQ/ldLcPuAOBQAJ

Comment: @crucifix94  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-safe-browsing-api/How$20to$20add$20rawhashes$20data%7Csort:date/google-safe-browsing-api/0ujjVp_NeWc/ttjpTZQjAwAJ